Payara 6, change the masterpassword, wrong initial password
I have acquired the latest payara 6 community edition from over here: https://www.payara.fish/downloads/payara-platform-community-edition/
This I placed inside a docker image of my own making. So far, so good. I may add, this self made docker container used to be working quire well with the payara inside and the .war it deployed, so you may assume that the payara instance in there is set up in a way, that did allow it to work within its expected boundaries, including working asadmin commands and an running app and correctly defined passwords. And it was already a Payara 6 before (from end 2023, I think).
Now I try to setup this new instance, and start doing this by changing the default passwords (inside the Dockerfile):
RUN echo "AS_ADMIN_NEWPASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}" >> /tmp/tmpFile &&\
    echo "AS_ADMIN_MASTERPASSWORD=changeit" >> /tmp/tmpFile &&\
    echo "AS_ADMIN_NEWMASTERPASSWORD=master" >> /tmp/tmpFile &&\
    echo "AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=" >> /tmp/tmpFile && \
    asadmin --user=${ADMIN_USER}  --passwordfile=/tmp/tmpFile  change-master-password && \
    asadmin --user=${ADMIN_USER}  --passwordfile=/tmp/tmpFile  change-admin-password --domain_name=${DOMAIN_NAME} && \

when the docker build comes past this section, it says this:
1.433 Incorrect current master password. You will not be able to change it.
1.433 Command change-master-password failed.

So.... every source I found in the web claims that an unchanged instance of Payara has the same masterpassword, which is supposed to be changeit
But, as you see, that does not work.
If I change the Dockerfile, so that the "change-admin-password" comes first, the normal admin password gets changed, so I assume that this location is in theory able to asadmin correctly. But, the masterpassword not so much...
I can choose to not setting the master password here, but then I do run into trouble later on, when it seems to be required to even start the server/domain.
If I run this interactively (without --password-file) later in the running container (with asadmin change-master-password), it will ask me for the current password, and changeit does not work there either.
I did look up in what I assume should be the current doc for Payara:
https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/Technical%20Documentation/Payara%20Server%20Documentation/Payara%20Server%20Docker%20Image.html#using-environment-variables
and it says... "changeit"
So... pardon my choice of wording, but dafuq? This is, as said above, an unchanged Payara community edition fresh from the website. What on earth can go wrong with such a simple task of changing a password which value is said to be predefined and kind of well documented?

You must be doing something wrong. The following works for me:
Dockerfile:
FROM payara/server-full

RUN echo "AS_ADMIN_NEWPASSWORD=mypassword" >> /tmp/tmpFile &&\
    echo "AS_ADMIN_MASTERPASSWORD=changeit" >> /tmp/tmpFile &&\
    echo "AS_ADMIN_NEWMASTERPASSWORD=master" >> /tmp/tmpFile &&\
    echo "AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}" >> /tmp/tmpFile && \
    asadmin --user=${ADMIN_USER}  --passwordfile=/tmp/tmpFile  change-master-password && \
    asadmin --user=${ADMIN_USER}  --passwordfile=/tmp/tmpFile  change-admin-password --domain_name=${DOMAIN_NAME}

Build with: ``docker build -t temp-payara .`
Produces this expected result (passwords are changed):
[+] Building 5.9s (6/6) FINISHED                                        docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 528B                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/payara/server-full:latest              0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/payara/server-full:latest                         0.0s
 => [2/2] RUN echo "AS_ADMIN_NEWPASSWORD=mypassword" >> /tmp/tmpFile &&    echo   5.8s
 => exporting to image                                                            0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                           0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:c3f8d879fb3b0edeb9a8a5cc8c1021bf5dd773b5992dc9420112  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/temp-payara                                    0.0s

